# Remap Mouse Wheel to Click/Key when other Key pressed down

Tags: mouse, autohotkey

I'm trying to remap my Mouse Wheel Up to send Click or Key while another key is pressed down.

Example: Shift is pressed down => Scrolling Up sends Click, Shift is not pressed down => Scrolling Up scrolls up.

I am using `Autohotkey`.

I tried something like this

`GetKeyState, state, Shift
If state = D
    WheelUp::Click`

But this doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check out the [`#if` directive](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_If.htm) for this.

Make sure you're running the [latest version of AHK](http://ahkscript.org/download/) for this to work properly.

```
#if, GetKeyState("Shift", "P")
    ; * = Fire the hotkey even if extra modifiers are being held down.
    *WheelUp::Send, {Lbutton}
#if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it much more simply:

```
+WheelUp::Send {LButton}
```